# Populating JList from another method that reads a text file

Tags: java, file-io, jlist

I'm trying to populate a JList with names which ultimately will be added to an AddressBook GUI.  I think I have the logic down which is, create the JList, populate it through a method which has read the names in from a text file, then add that JList to my panel.

My text file looks like this:

Family, Homer Simpson, 111 Homer Drive, Springfield, IL, 383838,....

The code in which it reads the file looks like this:

```js
 private void readContacts()
 {
  File cFile = new File ("Contacts.txt");
  BufferedReader buffer = null;
  ArrayList <String> contact = new ArrayList<String>();
  try
  {
   buffer = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (cFile));
   String text;
   
   while ((buffer.readLine()) != null)
   {
    String sep = buffer.readLine ( );
    String [] name = sep.split (",");
    text = name[1];
    contact.add(text);
    System.out.println (text);
    
   }
   
   
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
   
  }
  catch (IOException k)
  {
   
  }
 }
```

I know i'm doing something wrong with the code, because I'm getting NullPointerException here `String [] name = sep.split (",");`. Can anyone point me in the right direction, and after I successfully read the name in, how would I add that to a JList?  Thanks.

EDIT:

So, i've changed my method to return an ArrayList instead of void, and to populate the JList i'm using this:

```js
model = new DefaultListModel();
for (int i = 1; i < readContacts().size(); i++)
{
  model.addElement(i);
}
       
nameList = new JList (model);
add(nameList);
```

but it's just printing it out 1-10 as opposed to the the names. I'm assuming it's because I'm using `size()` instead of something else, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((buffer.readLine()) != null) { // read a line once  and check it's not null
    String sep = buffer.readLine(); // read the following line
```

You're reading two lines at each iteration. Just read one:

```
String sep;
while ((sep = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: that did the trick, now when I add this to my JList, would I just go about it like this? `nameList = new JList(readContacts));`  EDIT: Never mind that will work.

Comment: No. That doesn't add things to a JList. It creates a new one. You need to get the ListModel of the JList and add elements to this model. Rea the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable

Comment: Could you possibly check my edit, to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding i to the model. i is an integer going from 0 to the size of the list. So what you see is not really surprising. What you need to add is the element of the list which is at index i. Change your loop to `for (String name : readContacts()) { model.addElement(name); }`